# I want to invoke timer in my c# code on button click.It works well in form load event but didn't work in button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to invoke timer in my c# code on button click.It works well in form load event but didn't work in button click.Please help me to fix it.Thank's in advance.

My code is Here:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int TimeTaken;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblFilesCount.Text = lblFoldersCount.Text = "0";
    }

    private void btnFolderBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = fbdFoldersFiles.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbdFoldersFiles.SelectedPath);
            MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
        }
        txtFolderPath.Text = fbdFoldersFiles.SelectedPath;
    }
    private void btnDeleteFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerDelete.Enabled= true;
        string path = fbdFoldersFiles.SelectedPath;
        DirectoryInfo dirFirst = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        foreach (FileInfo file in dirFirst.GetFiles())
        {
            timerDelete.Enabled = true;
            DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(file.FullName);
            if (dt < dtpDate.Value)
            {
               DeleteFiles(file);
            }
        }
        string[] dirArray = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
        Array.Reverse(dirArray);
        foreach (var directory in dirArray)
        {
            if (Directory.GetFiles(directory).Length > 0 || Directory.GetDirectories(directory).Length>0)
            {
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles().ToArray();
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    timerDelete.Enabled = true;
                    DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(file.FullName);
                    if (dt < dtpDate.Value)
                    {
                        DeleteFiles(file);
                    }
                }
                if (Directory.GetFiles(directory).Length == 0 )
                {
                    dir.Delete(true);
                    lblFoldersCount.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(lblFoldersCount.Text) + 1).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        timerDelete.Enabled = false;
    }
    protected void DeleteFiles(FileInfo DeleteFile)
    {            
        dgvDisplayFilesInfo.Rows.Add();
        int RowIndex = dgvDisplayFilesInfo.RowCount - 1;
        DataGridViewRow r = dgvDisplayFilesInfo.Rows[RowIndex];
        r.Cells["dgvColoumnSrNo"].Value = RowIndex+1;
        r.Cells["dgvColumnFullName"].Value = DeleteFile.Name;
        r.Cells["dgvColumnPath"].Value = DeleteFile.Directory;
        DeleteFile.Delete();
        lblFilesCount.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(lblFilesCount.Text)+1).ToString();
    }

    private void timerDelete_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeTaken = TimeTaken++;
        lblShowTimeTaken.Text = TimeTaken.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are setting the Enabled=True in the `foreach` which I don't think it's what you intended. 2nd of all, why don't you use Stopwatch component. It's much easier to use.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
....
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString())
```

Comment: Sir i want to display counting on screen that's why i'm using timer.I'm not sure about stop watch that it provide this fuctionality. And the line you mentioned is misplaced in this post.